# <span> element adding a random space after word

Tags: html, css

I'm using Angular4 and I'm noticing this really weird issue where one of my `span` elements adds an extra space to the end of a word like this:

[image: screenshot]

The only CSS properties being set are `font-family`, `-webkit-font-smoothing`, `line-height` and `box-sizing`.

I tried changing the `word-spacing` and `white-space` properties but that did not work either. I've never encountered this issue before so any advice would be helpful

Comment: Can you paste the whole css associated with the span along with the css enforced by the parent. It will be helpful to resolve then. Like the class **key-ingredient**

Comment: can you give the link to the site

Comment: try changing font for a moment and see if it is font problem? sometime it is in the font

Comment: Here's the link to the site http://thelostexplorer.com/product/marula-head-to-toe-nourishment-oil . @AhmadGulzar I tried changing the font but that wasn't it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it wasn't a CSS issue but actually with the newlines in the template code.

Here was the code beforehand:

```
<span *ngFor="let ingredient of keyIngredients; let i = index;">
    <span *ngIf="i > 0">,&nbsp;</span>
    <span *ngIf="i === keyIngredients.length - 1">and&nbsp;</span>
    <span [innerHTML]="ingredient"></span>
</span>
```

I removed the newlines and put all the spans in one line to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your css : `padding-right: 0px; display: inline-block;`

Comment: There is no padding as seen from the picture

Answer (score 0):

in your css, just put display:inline-block to span elements

```
.key-ingredients span{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @chang-liu does it help you?